# Получение значения из массива и использование

Tags: jquery

Есть массив и выглядит он так:

```
var cat =[
['1','0','0','Action','','/action','0'],
['2','0','0','Shooter','','/shooter','0'],
['3','0','0','RPG','','/rpg','0'],
['4','0','0','Arcade','','/arcade','1'],
['5','0','0','Logic','','/logic','0'],
['6','0','0','Fighting','','/fighting','0'],
['7','0','0','Simulator','','/simulator','0'],
['8','0','0','Horror','','/horror','0'],
['9','0','0','Sport','','/sport','0'],
['10','0','0','Racing','','/racing','0']
];
```

Как сделать 10 ссылок используя значения из скаждой строки массива?
Типо

```
<a href="/action" data-id="1">Action</a>
<a href="/shooter" data-id="2">Shooter</a>
...
```

Заранее спасибо.

P.s.
Воздержитесь от комментариев, пожалуйста..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

типо так

```js
var cat =[
      ['1','0','0','Action','','/action','0'],
      ['2','0','0','Shooter','','/shooter','0'],
      ['3','0','0','RPG','','/rpg','0'],
      ['4','0','0','Arcade','','/arcade','1'],
      ['5','0','0','Logic','','/logic','0'],
      ['6','0','0','Fighting','','/fighting','0'],
      ['7','0','0','Simulator','','/simulator','0'],
      ['8','0','0','Horror','','/horror','0'],
      ['9','0','0','Sport','','/sport','0'],
      ['10','0','0','Racing','','/racing','0']
    ];
    
cat.forEach(function(v, idx){
     $("<a>").text(v[3])
             .data('id', v[0]) //attr('data-id', v[0])
             .attr('href', v[5])
             .appendTo('body');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

с новым синтаксисом можно и как то так написать

```
cat.forEach((v, idx) => {
   var [id,,,title,,url] = v;
   $("<a>").text(title)
           .data('id', id)
           .attr('href', url)
           .appendTo('body'); 
});
```

Comment: Спасибо больше)